# Eloquent Value of html select option not getting to controller to sort page

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

My controller doesn't seem to receive the value of the selected option i always get return of ''. I am trying to use this value to sort the view.
View:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sorteren" id="sorteren">
                    <option value="Name,asc">Name (A => Z)</option>
                    <option value="Name,Desc">Name (Z => A)</option>
                    <option value="Email,Asc">Email (A => Z)</option>
                    <option value="Email,Desc">Email (Z => A)</option>

      </select>
```

Controller

```
    $selectvalue = $request->input('sorteren');
    $selectvalue = explode(',', $selectvalue);




    $users = User::orderBy($selectvalue[0],$selectvalue[1])
```

Error i am getting:
"Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: Do you have the csrf token in your form? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: Yes, i have another input field of wich i do get the data to my controller

Comment: The code looks correct. This is a head scratcher for me.

Comment: What do you get using this `dd($request->input('sorteren'));` ?

Comment: I am trying to get the select option value here

Comment: try to dump what "$request->sorteren" return, because the "," in the request becomes something like "Email%2CAsc", and i'm not sure if those characters comes back to ","

Comment: Have you tried using `dd($request->input())` to see all input values from your request? Is there maybe another input with that name but no value?